# Flutter FCM Push Notification getting two notification in background

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Flutter FCM notification with an awesome_notification package, I am getting two notifications when handling onBackgroundMessage.

```dart
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  createNotification(message);
}

FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
```

Below is the object we pass in server.

```dart
def send_push_notification(message, title = 'Title', channel_id)
        options = {
          priority: 'high',
          data: { message: message },
          notification: {
            body: message,
            title: title
            title: title,
            android_channel_id: channel_id
          }
        }
```

```js
curl --location --request POST 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' \
--header 'Authorization: key='' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
"to" : user_token,
"notificaton": {
    
},
"data" : {
    "channelId":"session_alert",
    "title":"message title",
    "body":"message body",
}
}'
```

Then I searched so many StackOverflow answers they tell that remove notification field and send only the data field.
What happened is everything is working fine and getting notification in android (foreground/background/terminated), but in iOS (background/foreground) getting notification but I am not getting notification when app is in the terminated state on iOS.

can anyone please tell how to implement the right format to send notifications.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you added notification property in json object, FCM plugin will push a default notification according to the parameters you pass in that json.
And second notification must be your customized one which you might have triggered with data property values.
Solution to this will be removing the notification property from the json while sending the msg. I used postman to test this, you can test this as well.

```
{
"to" : user_token,
"notificaton": {}, // remove this 
"data" : {
    "channelId":"session_alert",
    "title":"message title",
    "body":"message body",
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I came across this post in 2023 after experiencing the same issue. According to this [feature request](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/discussions/6113) the flutter firebase team are not planning to implement a feature that allows you to turn off the feature where the SDK automatically displays a notification if the "notification" option exists in the payload ([doc ref](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/notifications/#displaying-notifications)).

I tried sending just a data notification but as mentioned [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage/#low-priority-messages) data notifications aren't guaranteed to be sent.

After lots of fiddling and tweaking I have managed to get around this by sending a notification option in the payload with a blank title and body

```
const message = {
      notification: {
        title: "",
        body: "",
      },
      data: {
        title: title,
        body: body,
        image: imageUrl,
      },
      token: registrationToken,
    };
```

This allowed me to send a notification with the app terminated (and in background) that was not intercepted by the firebase SDK and I could handle it on my own using Flutter Local Notifications.

```
/// Define a top-level named handler which background/terminated messages will
/// call. Be sure to annotate the handler with `@pragma('vm:entry-point')` above the function declaration.
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  //Handle notification with your chosen notifications package here...
  print('Handling a background message ${message.messageId}');
}

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  // Set the background messaging handler early on, as a named top-level function
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

To see the message with flutter terminated, plug a real device in then run "Flutter logs" in a terminal.

Hope this helps someone as I was looking for a long time how to get around this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use firebase_messaging  instead as per the awesome_notification plugin they are under development. https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications. one more thing when you have `notification` object inside fcm notification and if you app is in klled state or in background then it will automatically handled by system itself. you don'nt have to do anything for that.

If you send only `data` object then it will handled by app that time system can't do anything and for iOS it will not work.

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
   /// createNotification(message); /// comment out this code and check
}
```

Comment: exactly you said correct, but in background message, I need a small image in the right corner for that purpose I used an awesome notification package. you know how to customize the background notification.

Comment: I can say but this will not work for ios as in that we can't handle background push. you can tell what exactly you want to achieve